# Map circle overlay to lat/lng and radius in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created an overlay that I'd like to use to allow the user to select an area on the map. Problem is I need to map the position of 300px height and width circle in the middle of the screen to something that makes sense when I draw the circle.

This is what I tried:

```
  const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: mapRef.current,
      center: mapRef.current.getCenter(),
      radius: 100000 / (mapRef.current.getZoom() * mapRef.current.getZoom()),
    });
```

I'm thinking the center should just be the map's center but the problem is the radius. I tried to just insert some values but could never match it.

Can anybody lead me in the right direction?[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the bounding box in lat/lng, and then the width of the container in pixels. The ratio of width in longitudinal degrees divided by the width of the container, multiplied by 500 will give you the radius you want:

```
const elementWidth = 1000 // actual value
const mapBounds = mapRef.current.getBounds()
const radius = 500 * Mah.abs(mapBounds.getNorthEast().lng() - mapBounds.getSouthWest().lng()) / elementWidth
```